How do i find the fast and slow changing discrete time signals?
Here are some examples:
1.) Which of these discrete time signals have the fastest changing values:
a) $\cos\big(\tfrac{99}{100} \pi n \big)$
b) $\cos\big(\tfrac{49}{100} \pi n \big)$
c) $\cos\big(\tfrac{1}{100} \pi n \big)$
d) $\cos\big(\tfrac{199}{100} \pi n \big)$

I guess you could plot them.

We're not a shortcut to doing your homework. I believe the purpose of this question is to test if you understand what a derivative is and how to compute that.  What we can help with is specific questions where you are stuck when you show your work and that you've already spent the necessary time learning the assignment.

@DanBoschen, ain't no derivative.  I'm pretty sure that $n$ is always an integer.  But the rest of your comment counts.  I think there's a little trick in the question with $\tfrac{199}{100}\pi$ though.

I am not voting to close, to give people sufficient time to deal with part (d), which is, for a beginner, a teeny-weeny-tiny bit tricky.

@robertbristow-johnson yes good point; the discrete time equivalent of a derivative. And other point taken; I will retract my close vote

I would not say that there exists an "equivalent" to the derivative in discrete time.  I would say that $1-z^{-1}$ is the "counterpart" to the derivative in discrete time.  Sorta like that the Kronecker delta is the discrete-time counterpart to the Dirac delta.

Yes better word and one of many "counterparts" actually depending on how you map it. $2(1-z^{-1})/(1+z^{-1})$ is another.

Those are sinusoidal waves. When considering their associated frequency $f$, we write, for continuous time $t$:
$$x(t) = \sin(2\pi \cdot f \cdot t)$$
For discrete time:
$$x[n] = \sin \big(2\pi \cdot (f \cdot T_\mathrm{s}) \cdot n \big)$$
$n$ and $t$ are related by:
$$t = n \cdot T_\mathrm{s}$$
where $T_\mathrm{s}= \frac{1}{f_\mathrm{s}}$ is the sampling period.
From this explanation (introduction of any signals and systems textbook), you can easily find the high and low frequency signals, focusing on your specific problem.

There's a trick to part (d) of the question that is not sufficiently addressed in this answer.  I just wanted to clean up the answer a little, but I'll leave it to Filipe to maybe add to the answer to deal with part (d) of the question

@robertbristow-johnson, Thank you for brushing up the answer :) About the trick, I believe that you are mentioning that, since the signals are discrete, their periodicity $x[n]=x[n+T]$ might be different from $T_s$. In this case we must find the integer multiples of the frequency.

No no no.  $T_\mathrm{s}$ is a measure in time.  With dimension of time and units in, say, seconds.  The argument to $x[n]$ (which  is $n$) is simply a dimensionless number and an integer, to boot.  You do not add $T_\mathrm{s}$ to $n$.

ok, $T$ should be $N$. The purpose is to explain that continuous time periodicity mayb be different from discrete time periodicity. It is also possible that a signal is periodic in continuous time and non-periodic in discrete time (by the definition).

I think you have that backwards.  It doesn't matter whether it was periodic in continuous time or not, when you sample it and send a block of samples to the FFT, you just periodically extended the data.  The FFT (which is the DFT) always assumes $x[n+N]=x[n] \qquad \forall n, N \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $X[k+N]=X[k] \qquad \forall k, N \in \mathbb{Z} $,
